# How to grep errors from log files but filter off false alerts?

Tags: regex, logging, grep, pcre

The goal is to get output as below, containing file name and error count for each file.

```
/var/log/file2.log:5
/var/log/file3.log:7
/var/log/file5.log:3
/var/log/file7.log:2
```

Assuming there are many log files named "`*.log`" and all are in same format as below.

```
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassAAAA      : real error
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassAAAA      : message
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibBB          : real error
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibBB          : message
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassCCCCCC    : real error
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassCCCCCC    : real error
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassCCCCCC    : message
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassD         : false alert
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.ClassD         : message
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibEEE         : false alert
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibEEE         : message
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibFFFFF       : false alert
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001 ERROR 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibFFFFF       : false alert
2021-03-16 01:01:01.001  INFO 1234 --- [main] com.example.LibFFFFF       : message
```

The major problem is that there are some known false alerts that shouldn't be counted.

For example, we hope to count errors logged by any class other than `ClassD`, `LibEEE` and `LibFFFFF` by below commmand.

```
grep -Pc '^.* ERROR .*((?<!(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF)).)*$' *.log | grep -v :0
```

But it doesn't work and below error is printed.

```
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

If it worked, the count would be 4 for above example log piece, logged by `ClassAAAA`, `LibBB` and `ClassCCCCCC` respectively.

### **UPDATE**

Sincerely thank all of you for taking the time to share your idea. The reason I went into the think set of lookbehind is that I'd like to qualify the class name by "`\s*:`" initially, but the space and colon was missed eventually.

Though the goal can be achieved for now, just curious - is it possible to use lookbehind in this case?

Comment: What are the expected matches? Why not use a negative _lookahead_ rather than a negative lookbehind?

Comment: Then why use a lookbehind? Use a lookahead: `grep -Pc '\sERROR(?!.*(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF))\s' | grep -v :0`

Comment: look behind alternation should be of equal length. If you can get away with `LibFFF` only instead of `LibFFFFF` then `^.* ERROR .*((?<!(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFF)).)*$` would be fine.

Comment: You ask if a lookbehind can be used. Yes, but in cases like yours, with regex, lookaheads are more natural.

Answer (score 4):

This should be a task for `awk`, could you please try following.
Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. You could pass multiple files to this command and it will print file by file(with filename and errors count like shown samples).

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS=":" }
FNR==1{
  if(count){
    print FILENAME,count
  }
  count=0
}
/ERROR/ && !/ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF/{
  count++
}
END{
  if(count){
    print FILENAME,count
  }
}
'  *.log
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ OFS=":" }             ##Setting OGFS to colon in BEGIN section of this program.
FNR==1{                      ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  if(count){                 ##Checking if count is not null then.
    print FILENAME,count     ##Printing file name with OFS and count value here.
  }
  count=0                    ##Setting count to 0 here.
}
/ERROR/ && !/ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF/{  ##checking condition if line does not contain ClassD, LibEEE and LibFFFFF then do following.
  count++                    ##Increase count with 1 here.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(count){                 ##Checking if count is not null then.
    print FILENAME,count     ##Printing file name with OFS and count value here.
  }
}
'  *.log                     ##Passing all .log files to program here.
```

Answer (score 3):

To print the correct filenames:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {
  if (c)
    print f,c
  c=0
  f=FILENAME
}
$3=="ERROR" && $7!~/ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF/ {
  ++c
}
END {if (c) print f,c}
' *.log
```

or less typing but more memory usage:

```
awk '
$3=="ERROR" && $7!~/ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF/ {
  ++c[FILENAME]
}
END {for (f in c) print f,c[f]}
' *.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a PCRE regex lookbehind, there can only be patterns of different length on the *top* level: `(?<!ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF)`is fine, but `(?<!(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF)).` is not as the alternations are inside a capturing group.

Actually, here, you can use a lookahead where the length of the alternatives does not matter:

```r
grep -Pc '\sERROR(?!.*(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF))\s' | grep -v :0
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7mUXDA/1).

This pattern matches

- `\s` - any whitespace
- `ERROR` - a substring
- `(?!.*(ClassD|LibEEE|LibFFFFF))` - a negative lookahead that matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with one of the words in the group
- `\s` - any whitespace

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
$ awk '
    ($3=="ERROR") && $7 !~ /\.(ClassD|Lib(EEE|FFFFF))$/ { c++ }
    ENDFILE { printf "%s:%d\n", FILENAME, c; c=0 }
' file*
file:4
```